# Unable to run emulator on a virtual machine due to gpu driver issue.Is it possible to run avd in vm or nested vm?

Tags: android-studio

I have installed Android studio on windows 10 vm running on ovirt host.
Once i run the emulator , it has a GPU Driver issue.

Tried all the possible solutions:
 1.I've changed the GPU Performance from automatic to software renderer
 2.Installed HAXM
 3.Disabled Hyper-v

Still I'm facing the same issue. Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I have the same issue.